# Laravel, Auth and logging out from a model

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm currently using Laravel 5 Authentification, but I have edited it to allow me to connect to an API server instead of an Eloquent model.

Here is the code of my custom UserProvider:

```
<?php namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as UserProviderInterface;
use WDAL;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;
use Session;

class WolfUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    private $_loggedUser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_loggedUser = null;
        $user = Session::get('user');

        if (!empty($user)) {
            $this->_loggedUser = unserialize($user);
        }
    }

    public function retrieveById($id)
    {
        return $this->_loggedUser;
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        //dd('updateRememberToken');
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        $user = WDAL::getContactCredentials($credentials['login']);

        return $user;
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {


        if($user->username == $credentials['login'] && $user->password == $credentials['password']){
            $this->_loggedUser = $user;
            Session::set('user', serialize($user));     

           return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

This code might not be perfect as it still in early development ;-) (feel free to suggest me some ideas of improvement if you want to)

So when the user is logged, it has access to the whole platform and to several views and can communicate with the API server to display and edit data.

Sometimes, the API server can return "Invalid Session ID" and when my Model gets this message, the user should be redirected to the login page.

From a Controller it's really easy to handle I can use this code (logout link):

```
public function getLogout()
{
    $this->auth->logout();
    Session::flush();


    return redirect('/');
}
```

But do you know how I should proceed from a Model ? I could of course edit all my controllers to check for the value returned by the Model to logout, but cannot it be done thanks to middlewares?
It seems to be really long to edit all my controllers, and this will imply a lot of duplicated code.

Answer (score 0):

One of my tries was to throw an exception from the Controller, and catch in from the auth middleware.
It was not working, because I didn't write `use Exception;`

I'm now catching the exception, and can now redirect the user from the middleware.

Thank you anyway!